# Python: Evaluating an Isolation Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, evaluation, unsupervised-learning

I am doing isolation forest clustering on the the mulcross database with 2 classes. I divide my data into training and test set and try to calculate the accuracy score, the roc_auc_score and the confusion_matrix on my test set. But there are two problems: The first one is that in a clustering method i should not use the labels in the training phase, it means that *"y_train"* should not be mentioned, but i did not find another solution to evaluate my model. More over the results i found are wrong. 
**My problem is how to evaluate a clustering model like isolation forest.**
Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('db.csv')
y_true=df['Target']
df_data=df.drop('Target',1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_data, y_true, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

alg=IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, max_samples= 256 , contamination=0.1, max_features=1.0, bootstrap=False, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42, verbose=0, behaviour="new")
model = alg.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = alg.predict(X_test)

print("#############################\n#############################")
print(accuracy_score(y_test, preds))
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, preds))
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, preds)
print(cm)
print("#############################\n#############################")
```

Comment: why would you use clustering if you have labels? Try something supervised, like RandomForest.

Comment: I have to evaluate an isolation forest. And for the labes i did remove them with the function drop()

Comment: same question again.. If you don't answer this question people will allways tell you its a classification task because you have labels. So   ***why*** would you not use supervised learning?

Comment: because the idea with isolation forest is to only use the labels to compare model performance with each other. The models themselves do not see the labels.we are actually doing clustering. This is a simple explication of an isolation Forest in order to understand the idea  [link](https://www.kaggle.com/rgaddati/unsupervised-fraud-detection-isolation-forest)

Comment: Isolation forest are not clustering. You also don't do train test splits, because you are not actually training anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why are you clustering and dividing it into training/testing sets. It seems to me like you are mixing classification/clustering or something like that. If you have labels, try a supervised method. Easy winnings are xgboost, random forest, GLM, logistic, etc...

If you want to evaluate clustering methods, you can investigate the inter- and intra-cluster distances. At the end of the day, you want to have small and well-separated clusters. You can look at a metric called silhouette too.

You can also try

`print("Accuracy:", list(y_pred_test).count(1)/y_pred_test.shape[0])`

also, look [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rgaddati/unsupervised-fraud-detection-isolation-forest) for some more details.

Comment: You are right. In fact, Isolation Forest is an unsupervised method and as I read for these methods, the evaluation is done according to the algorithm, it means that there is not a generic way to evaluate a model as for the supervised methods. Do you have an idea what to change in my code so that i can evaluate an isolation Forest? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but the link you mentioned to me is the first one I used. But I have not found correct results. My problem is what are the steps to follow in order to evaluate an isolation forest.

Comment: You can run the piece of code I gave you in the answer so to obtain the accuracy of your forest.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the auc score? i found it 52.8%, whish is not logic at all.

Comment: An AUC of 0.53 means that your model has almost no class separation capacity.